# Структура в Rust с не одним временем жизни не работает

Tags: rust

Есть такой Rust код:

```
struct User<'a,'b> {
    //conn field TODO: fill.
    auth: Cell<'a + Option<'b + Box<dyn 'b + AuthT>>>,
    st: State<'a>,
}
```

Смысл в том, что в структуре есть ячейка с необязательным указателем на объект. Мне нужно чтоб когда ячейка заполяеться ничем(Option::None), то вариант автоматически освобождал объект на куче.

Впрочем, компилятор со мной не согласен:

```
tema3210@tema2-devhost:~/rustfun$ cargo check
    Checking rustfun v0.1.0 (/home/tema3210/rustfun)
error[E0404]: expected trait, found struct `Box`
  --> src/main.rs:12:25
   |
12 |     auth: Cell<'a + Option<'b + Box<dyn 'b + AuthT>>>
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a trait
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Более полное описание кода или минимизация примера не помешали бы, а то не сильно понятно, например, зачем нужен Cell и второе ВЖ. Но так как ты попытался распихать по типам ВЖ - оно в принципе не работает, ВЖ нужны только для ссылок или параметризации типов.

По описанию задачи могу предложить вот такой упрощенный и компилирующийся код:

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;

struct State<'a> { data: &'a u8 }

trait AuthT {}

struct AuthS;

impl AuthT for AuthS {}

struct User<'a> {
    auth: Cell<Option<Box<dyn AuthT>>>,
    st: State<'a>,
}

fn main() {
    let user = User {
        auth: Cell::new(Some(Box::new(AuthS))),
        st: State { data: &0 }
    };
    user.auth.set(None);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=08a028a42eaa34d20872f4d44ee79bc3)

Так поле "auth" вполне можно через внутреннюю мутабельность сбросить в `None` и указатель на `AuthT` будет освобожден.